# fronted verb with relative pronoun: to buy which

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

Is the following use of "to buy which" correct?

> John likes several houses, **to buy which** over ten million dollars will be required.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: In this example, would over $10M be required to buy all the houses, or any one of those houses?

Comment: That question is beside the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I should've been clearer - the sentence as currently written is incorrect. The correct version differs based on whether the cost is for all the houses or each of the houses.

Comment: Anyway I'll give both answers :)

Comment: I'll write the sentence as follows : "John likes several houses, which will require ten million dollars to buy" OR "John likes several houses, which will cost him over ten million dollars." OR, "It costs over ten million dollars to buy several houses John likes."

Comment: It's ambiguous in that we're not certain whether the $10m is the cost of all the houses or just one or some of them, though the former is implied. That aside, I don't think it's ungrammatical. The relative phrase is "to buy which", where "which" is object of "buy" and has "several houses" as antecedent. The logical variables can be represented as: "John likes _several x_"; to buy _several x_ over 10 million dollars will be required".

Comment: @BillJ Does the same ambiguity exist in "John likes several houses, which will cost over ten million dollars"?

Comment: Yes, it's just another way of saying the same thing.

Comment: Some, or perhaps many, people say "to buy which" sounds odd.

Comment: Yes: even without any ambiguity, the infinitival construction is quite rare. There are alternatives, as RuslanD mentions in their answer.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence as written is incorrect. You can read [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/which) and [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/relative-pronouns#relative-pronouns__107) about how to form relative clauses with "which". In short, you should either use "which" by itself to start a relative clause, or in combination with a preposition - e.g. "in which", "with which", "(some/none/most/etc) of which", etc.

If your sentence means to convey the idea that each of the houses costs over 10 million dollars, I'd rephrase it as:

> John likes several houses, **each of which** costs over 10 million dollars. (the verb "cost" is a shorter way of saying what you mean)
>
> John likes several houses, **each of which** can be bought for over 10 million dollars.
>
> John likes several houses, **each of which** requires over 10 million dollars for a purchase.

If, instead, you want to convey that the houses *together* cost over 10 million dollars, you could say:

> John likes several houses, **which** *together* cost over 10 million dollars.
>
> John likes several houses, **all of which** cost over 10 million dollars *combined*.
>
> John likes several houses, whose combined cost is over 10 million dollars.